# How do I reference HttpClient in mono?

Tags: c#, mono

I want to compile and run the file below using mono but I get compile errors

```
dmcs test.cs -r:System.Net.Http
```

> error CS0006: Metadata file `System.Net.http' could not be found
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

```
dmcs test.cs -r:System.Net
```

> test.cs(1,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Http' does not exist in the namespace`System.Net'. Are you missing `System.Net.Http' assembly reference?

Source

```
using System.Net.Http;
public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HttpClient c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add an assembly reference. Why do you use command line? Cannot you install MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio?

Comment: @LexLi Maybe I'll install it on a VM but that's a little overkill to find the reference name. I'm compiling the code on my PI. I had it running on my pi a year ago but IDR the reference I used and I may have had mono installed on my old laptop which I no longer have

Comment: cross compile is possible so I don't think you have to work on PI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 14.04, the default SDK is 4.0, but `System.Net.Http` is available in version 4.5.

```
dmcs Program.cs -r:System.Net.Http -sdk:4.5
```

Or from MonoDevelop: ProjectOptions->Build->General->Target framework: `Mono/.NET 4.5`